# How to make phosphorescent material

Tags: materials, shaders, light

I was wondering if it's possible to make a phosphorescent material that stores the light-energy. I don't mean like fluorescent just by putting a emmision shader.

I mean if light shines on it and then you mute the light, the material stores the light for a period of time until it fades out into darkness. You get this material sometimes on the pointer of analog wristwatches or like on fluorescent jackets.

Hope my explanation is clear

Comment: You mean phosphorus material. Iam not familiar with materials editing, but I guess that sub surface and some light emission will do the job. Just remember that light emission is for cycle renderer in eevee there will be no reflection I think

Comment: It would be nice to fetch a reference image of what you want to achieve, so we can pinpoint a clear response.

Comment: https://imgur.com/CGLhciB

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkEL59ex8qU

Comment: Something like this, but when you turn of the light the lighted surface keeps glowing for, say like, 5 seconds

Comment: then you want an animation?

Comment: Yes! Like glow in the dark material but after some seconds it fades away

Comment: Sorry for not metioning this earlier, new to this site

Comment: Then the headline description is wrong, You need to ask for an animation of light fading away. Iam not an animator but it will be easy one, where you set the intensity of light lower and lower through few key frames.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do this with Blender, there is no way to retrieve "light incidence" per surface nor is it possible store a "history" of this data. You would have to manually create some sort on animated texture representing light intensity

Comment: Thank you very much Ramos!! That's an answer to my question

Comment: I'll try to maybe work with nodes, if the normal of the face lines up more with the source of the light it should emit more light.

Answer (score 1):

[I provided a video for better clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlHrh.jpg), also used Eevee because the render is fast, but you can use cycles too.

What you want is to simply animate a emission property and a light brightness, in the case of cycles, you could use only the emission shader.

You will also need another shader when the light fades off, so you mix the emission with the other shader, for a nice effect, I applied the same texture to the emitter. To the sphere to not cast shadow, I simply set the shadows to none in the materials tab.

[image]

Comment: Allright, thank you so much, I understand this but I don't mean the entire material, only the material that is affected by the outside light. https://imgur.com/a/8gp8BHm I made a visualization on imgur